# (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.ddahl#jvmr_2.10;2.11.2.1: not found

Tags: scala, sbt

I apologize in advance if I am missing any piece of information.I am trying to use external library jvmr.jar with my scala project.I get following error during compile process:

```
**(*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.ddahl#jvmr_2.10;2.11.2.1: not found**
```

here is my build.scala file

```
import sbt._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "modern-web-template"
  val appVersion      = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0",
    "javax.inject" % "javax.inject" % "1",
    "org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.10.0",
    "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "0.10.2",
    "org.ddahl" %% "jvmr" % "2.11.2.1",
    "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.9.5" % "test"
  )



  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here      
  )

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have used

```
"org.ddahl" %% "jvmr" % "2.11.2.1"
```

resolver looks for artifact named `jvmr_2.10` and version `2.11.2.1`

If you would like to search for version 2.11.2.1 of artifact **jvmr_2.11** you need to set scala verions:
perhaps `scalaVersion := "2.11.4"` in your build.sbt.
Using double **%%** in artifact definition causes sbt appends scalaVersion to artifact name. Many scala artifacts comes with _2.10 and _2.11 suffixes.
You can also define dependecy as:

```
"org.ddahl" % "jvmr_2.11" % "2.11.2.1"
```

with single percent sign - sbt won't append any suffix.

Comment: Thank you, however, it did not make any difference, still the same error: (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.ddahl#jvmr_2.11;2.11.2.1: not found